# Speckle on LiDAR data

Tags: lidar, noise

Does LiDAR data suffer from the speckle noise like the SAR images and ultrasound cardiac images I'm used to?

I think speckle noise is inherent to all active sensors, but I'm not sure for LiDAR because all the freely-accessible elevation images for the UK I worked with have a high-resolution (25cm, 50cm, 1m, 2m). They might have gone through a preprocessing,  and anyway if the speckle is there it's really hard to spot.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. A lot of work goes into making the speckles 'noise class', some can be done automatically but to get the data really clean manual intervention is required. You would need a good 3d editor to view profiles and classify noise. Some causes of noise can be clouds, insects, reflecting off shiny objects but in a minority of cases there doesn't appear to be a good reason for noise in the data.

Comment: While speckle type noise is present in LiDAR, I would say that it contributes far less to the general roughness of LiDAR DEMs than micro-topography (i.e. surface roughness). This is particularly the case under forest cover. That is, when we see a rough non-LiDAR DEM, we assume the roughness is due to noise (elevation error), while in LiDAR data sets, this surface property is frequently the result of actual surface roughness more so than noise.